# admin area: Restrict access to a particular page

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, acl

I want to hide or restrict access to a particular page from admin users.
That means if an admin user tried to reach a page (e.g.  `System > Tools > Compilation` ) he/she would see a 404 not found notice (like when you install an extension, before you log out and log back in).

I read some information about `ACL` in Magento, but I'm not sure if this is the place to start.

How can I do this? I'm developing an extension for this task.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry. I should have said that I'm writing an extension for this task and the extension should restrict access to both current users and future users.

Comment: instead of giving admin credentilas, dont you want to create new users and give credentials ?

Comment: System -> Permissions -> Roles set acl permission for particular user

Answer (score 2):

You can create New roles for those users in **System > Permission > Roles**

[image]

You can create new users in Magento Backend :

**System > Permission > Users > Add New User** and enter below details and Assign the User to Role :

[image]

you can check below links for more information :

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/permissions-user-new.html

https://www.simplehelix.com/blog/magento/14930/

https://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/users-and-user-roles

Answer (score 0):

You should create new roles with the correct permissions and add users for which you want to assign those privileges. Please refer to this excellent tutorial for more detailed info: http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. You should rewrite the corresponding controller class. For example if you want to restrict access to Notifications page, you should find its controller and rewrite its `_isAllowed()` method. Like this:

In `config.xml`:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Your_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Your_Module_Adminhtml</Your_Module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Create `app/code/local/Your/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/NotificationController.php`:

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php';
class Your_Theme_Adminhtml_NotificationController extends Mage_Adminhtml_NotificationController {
    protected function _isAllowed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```